# Where is the git submodule revision actually stored?

Tags: git, cicd

I understand how to use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to reference a specific commit in another repo, but where is that reference actually stored? It doesn't seem to be in `.gitmodules` as plain text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.gitmodules` file just records the path and remote URL to the submodule repository. The commit itself is stored in the tree object. You can query it like this:

```
git ls-tree <ref> <path>
```

where `<ref>` is a reference to some commit (e.g. `HEAD`, `master`, a commit SHA sum) and `<path>` is a path to a submodule.

The output looks something like this:

```
160000 commit <sha> <path>
```

where `<sha>` is the commit in the submodule. The number in front has the following meaning, according to [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> Notice the `160000` mode for the `DbConnector` *(submodule path of the example used in the book)* entry. That is a special mode in Git that basically means you’re recording a commit as a directory entry rather than a subdirectory or a file.

See also [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033441/1347968).